# Muti threaded program that displays all prime numbers smaller than one entered

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a program that displays all prime numbers below the one entered by the user. The only requirement is that it must be multi threaded. This is my first time using Java and multiple threads. Can you help? It compiles, but the output is strange. Maybe it's an address?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class prime {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // get number from user
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();

        RunPrime runprime1 = new RunPrime (num);
        runprime1.start();
        Thread.yield();

        runprime1.SmallerPrimeNumbers();
    }
}

class RunPrime extends Thread {

    private int given_number;

    RunPrime (int n) {
        given_number = n;
    }

    public void SmallerPrimeNumbers() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= given_number; i++) {
            if (CheckPrime(i)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= given_number; j++) {
                if (CheckPrime(j)) {
                    number[i] = j;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(number);
    }

    public static boolean CheckPrime (int n) {
        for (int i=2 ; i<n ; i++) {
            if (n%i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm trying to get used to the way this site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SmallerPrimeNumbers()` function has a second for-loop that doesn't look necessary.  You're also assigning and printing the variable `number` that wasn't declared anywhere (this is probably what's causing you trouble).  Since you're only printing them and not saving them, you can simplify the function like this:

```
public void SmallerPrimeNumbers() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= given_number; i++) {
        if (CheckPrime(i)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```